# Javascript - add anchor for design reasons

Tags: javascript, redirect, anchor

i have a tiny JS problem:
If a user visits a special site `http://www.test.de` i would like to automatically add an anchor to that url for design reasons -> result `http://www.test.de/#welcome`.

After 10 seconds i would like to change the anchor to http://www.test.de/#thankyou

Is this possible in some way? Maybe with window.location?

big thx for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `window.location.hash` here

```
window.onload = function(){
  window.location.hash = 'welcome';

  setTimeout( function(){
    window.location.hash = 'thankyou';
  }, 10*1000);
};
```

Comment: @Matt -- the creepy part is that I was also adding an answer that looked almost exactly the same! :-)

Comment: @Matt Ball, haha, +1 for you ;)

Comment: @Sean: that's exactly what I was referring to. Harmen - same to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    window.location.hash = '#welcome';
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = '#thankyou';
    }, 10*1000);
}
```

[MDC `window.onload()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)

[MDC `window.location.hash` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location.hash)

Comment: You do not explicitly need the `#` here, but it might be easier to understand. On the other hand, `window.location.hash` will always return the value including the `#`

Comment: @Harmen: because it always returns a value including the `#`, I like to always set it to a value that includes the `#`. Bloody magic properties...

Comment: is window.location.hash supported in IE<7?

Comment: @Tom Auger: why not try it for yourself and see?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question - remapping `www.test.de` to `www.test.de/#welcome` can be done using URL rewriting. See [mod_rewrite for Apache installations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) or [urlrewrite for IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

The second could easily be done using a JavaScript timer and window.location as you have suggested.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout("window.location.href='http://www.test.de/#thankyou'", 10000); // 10 secs
</script>
```

Although I would question this approach from a user experience perspective. If you are actually referring to specific anchors within the document body, then the user might be dismayed to find his screen jumping to a new part of the page after 10 seconds. If there are no corresponding anchors, then it's just odd (though not necessarily bad).

Comment: Ugh, _please_ don't advise people to pass strings to `setTimeout()`. Ever.

Comment: Okay,sorry: setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='http://www.test.de/#thankyou'}, 10000); // matt prefers a closure